# Scan from Jenkins for on successfull github action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-actions, pull

I have a GitHub action which gets triggered on merge to master

```
name: master_stable

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

Following are the tasks this workflow accomplishes:

- Run test cases to check if the master is stable or not
- If the master is stable, it will build the Docker image and upload it to ECR
- Trigger a Jenkins pipeline which will deploy this image to the Kubernetes cluster

Now my Jenkins machine is behind a private VPC and it is not callable from Github.

What I want to accomplish is to build a Jenkins job, which will keep scanning for a particular Github action, and when it finds one successful run, trigger itself. Similar to how it checks for PR and tags in Github repo.

Is there a way to do this from Jenkins? Is there a pull mechanism for Github Actions which I can use from Jenkins for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the github actions api to get information about your workflows. Just create a token in github and call api normally from jenkins

Solution 1:
Get workflows list by workflow file name or id if you have it
https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow-runs/#list-workflow-runs and get

Solution 2:
Get workflows list by repo name
https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow-runs/#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository

In case you need it,
How to create tokens in github
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token